# Why use <script> element as template is much more popular than other elements?

Tags: javascript, html, templates

I had just tried that using `<style>` tag can do exactly the same thing as what `<script>` tag does if someone need a template. But I cannot find any usage on the internet about using `<style type="text/x-template">`.

So, my question is... Why `<script>` is preferred? Any historical reason or browser compatibility reason here?

Here is a demo:

```js
(function () {
  let output = document.getElementById('output');
  let template = document.getElementById('template');
  let dom = document.createElement('div');
  dom.innerHTML = template.innerHTML;
  dom.getElementsByClassName('todo')[0].textContent = '42';
  output.appendChild(dom);
}());
```

```html
<style id="template" type="text/x-template">
<div>This is from template!</div>
<div class="todo"></div>
<div>This is from template too!</div>
</style>
<div>something before output:</div>
<span id="output">
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Great question, though I don't think theres a great answer for that.

Those templates are usually read and processed by javascript code. Thus it makes a lot more sense to identify them by using a `<script>` tag compared to a `<style>` tag that is for CSS.

Nowadays you would use a [template tag as described here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template).

Sadly [IE 11 still doesn't support it, but the rest of browser support is pretty good](http://caniuse.com/#feat=template)